# Is there any parseable process monitor?

Tags: process, monitoring

I'm looking for a process monitor that produce an easy to parse output to stdout. Is there any tool like that in unix? Something like `htop` or `top`, but mean to be consumed by another program.

To be more specific, let's say i want to create a gui program for process monitoring. So, I need to get a real time process information (maybe every second). Do I need to call `ps` every second, or maybe there's a better alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [`ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)... It can be configured to output specific information on specific processes (or all processes).

If you don’t mind making your program OS-specific, you could also parse whatever `ps` parses on your system, *e.g.* `/proc` on a Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

Top has an option to run and exit, it's called the batch mode. I've used this to get the status of a process in a script in the past.

```
top -bn1
```

-b is for batch mode
-n1 tells it to run once.

Answer (score -1):

If you have nodejs installed, you can use the package [`linux-top-parser`](https://github.com/sweetim/linux-top-parser)

It will parse the top output into JSON, you can access them using the API or the CLI.

Comment: While this is technically correct it doesn't answer the spirit of the question. Using nodejs, let alone a specific package that has dependencies itself is really overkill. This is why I downvoted this answer.

Comment: This is to provide additional alternative for the user, as the user also mention to develop a gui application, using nodejs and electron this package would be an option